# Change Result in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I want to change the result of one of my steps in my jenkins pipeline to be **UNSTABLE** instead of **FAILURE**.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
steps {
  withMaven(maven: mavenTool, jdk: jdkTool) {
    sh 'mvn verify'
  }
}
post {
  failure {
    script {
      manager.build.buildUnstable()
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have experience with declarative jenkins pipelines?

Comment: what happens with your current attempt? i do believe that you can't change the status to something better, only from something better to something worse.

Comment: nothing happens. Maybe you are right and i can't change the result to something better. But i think you should have the choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
steps {
  withMaven(maven: mavenTool, jdk: jdkTool) {
    sh 'mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true verify'
}
post {
   always {
      junit(testResults: '**/surefire-reports/*xml', allowEmptyResults: true)
   }
}
```

The `maven.test.failure.ignore` is a [config parameter](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) of the Maven Surefire plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating this for the addition of [warnError](https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/07/05/jenkins-pipeline-stage-result-visualization-improvements/); You can now instead wrap the failing step as a warning ("unstable" build), e.g.:

```
 warnError('Maven tests failed!') {
   sh 'mvn verify'
 }
```

That way you have visibility into the failures.